# access 3D Mat cell position uting pointer

Tags: opencv, pointers, 3d, mat

I am trying to access a 3D Mat object, but I don't know how to do it.

In the 2D case i can access any matrix position in a double for cycle over "i" and "j" simply with the following command:

```
float a = M.ptr<float>(i)[j];
```

Do you know how I can do it in the case I have a 3D matrix? I have tried with

```
float a = M.ptr<float>(i)(j)[k];
```

and

```
float a = M.ptr<float>(i)[j][k];
```

but they are not working. I don't want to use .at(i,j,k) because it is very slow.

Comment: I have solved it this way: float a = M.ptr<float>(i)[j,j];

Comment: "at" isn't _very slow_ , also your solution doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it this way:

```
float a = M.ptr<float>(i)[j,k];
```